# How to customize API endpoint URL based on logged-in user?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, url

I'm working on an API project that allows users to perform various actions such as login, registration, updating, and deleting their account. Currently, the base URL for these endpoints is:

```bash
localhost:8080/api/v1/user/auth
```

However, I would like to customize the endpoint URL based on the logged-in user, so that it looks something like this:

```bash
localhost:8080/api/v1/user/${username}
```

This way, users would only be able to access data that is specific to their account. Can anyone suggest a way to achieve this using URL parameters or any other method?

I'm developing the API using **Nodejs** **Expressjs** , and any examples or code snippets would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: protected & unprotected routes should always be seperate, meaning "auth" routes should be outside of "user" resource.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [route parameters](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#route-parameters) in Express to have a "variable" in the URL:

```js
app.get('/api/v1/user/:username', (req, res) => {
  const username = req.params.username; // This will be the username from the URL

  // ...
});
```

Any requests to `localhost:8080/api/v1/user/ANY_TEXT_HERE` will be handled by this endpoint. Then you can use the username and handle it accordingly.

Keep in mind that the username in the request could very easily be forged, so make sure to implement some kind of access control system so that other users cannot access private information from another user.